# can't produce any content on minimal blogger template

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I'm trying to create new template from scratch, following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfsUIC71Ouc) video.

In my case it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
<head>
<title>
abc title
</title>
<b:skin><![CDATA[
h1{
color:red;
}
]]></b:skin>
</head>

<body>
<b:section id='sc01'>
  <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
  </b:section>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is no `lorem ipsum` on loading page.
The page is empty, console is clear.
In page source code I see:

`<div class='no-items section' id='sc01'></div>`

Any help?

Comment: Try placing `<h1>lorem ipsum</h1>` before `<b:section id='sc01'>`

Comment: [From the documentation on sections](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46888) "A section can only contain widgets."

Comment: @Roshan, thanks a lot, solved. You could place your comment as answer.

Comment: @puerto you're most welcome. Glad it did. :)

Comment: @puerto thank you. Please upvote if it's useful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<h1>lorem ipsum</h1>` before `<b:section id='sc01'>`.